# How magento 1.7 creates new shipment from admin area?

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, email, invoice, shipment

I have the following problem with magento 1.7.0.2 - shipment and invoice emails are not sent to the customer who placed the order. However, these emails are sent to the email addresses that are set in magento area in Send Invoice Email Copy To and Send Shipment Email Copy To. I've managed to track the process of sending these emails in magento core files but I cannot find where and how magento admin area calls a function to create a new shipment when the button submit shipment is clicked. If you have any suggestions please help.

Answer (score 1):

The shipment is saved in `Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_ShipmentController::saveAction()`.
The e-mail is sent from `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Shipment::sendEmail()`.
If you don't have any extensions or custom code that changes the behavior of sending e-mails, the e-mail should be sent without any issues. If the e-mail arrives to one of the store e-mail addresses then it might be an issue with the customer's e-mail address (maybe it ends up in spam).

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.I had a look at sendEmail and it has 2 parameters.If $notifyCustomer = true(the default value)then the shipment email is sent both to the customer and the store emails,if not the shipment email is sent only to the store emails set in the Send Shipment Email Copy To field.That is why I would like to see the instance of the function when it is called and its 1st parameter.I suppose that when this sendEmail function is called its first parameter $notifyCustomer is set to false and hence the result is-sending the sipment email only to store emails,not to customer.

Comment: However, if you add manually the customer email in the Send Shipment Email Copy To field, then the shipment email is sent correctly, which means that it's not an issue with the customer's e-mail address.